# Git/GitHub can't push to master

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git/GitHub and ran into an issue. I created a test project and added it to the local repository. Now I am trying to add files/project to the remote repository.

Here's what I did (and this worked) -

```
git remote add origin git://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

Now when I try to push the repository to GitHub, using the following command, I get the following error -

```
git push origin master
```

Error -

```
fatal: remote error:
You can't push to git://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
Use git@github.com:my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

Comment: There's a help link (http://help.github.com/) at the bottom of all the github pages.  The help describe many topics including this one.  I'd suggest reading those and then asking questions about specific things you don't understand.

Comment: if jamessan had pointed to a specific location in the help pages, that would have been more useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git github cannot push to origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101203/git-github-cannot-push-to-origin)

Comment: If you are reading this Mar 17th 2022, check down detector. Github is failing.

Answer (score 249):

GitHub doesn't support pushing over the Git protocol, which is indicated by your use of the URL beginning `git://`. As the error message says, if you want to push, you should use either the SSH URL `git@github.com:my_user_name/my_repo.git` or the "smart HTTP" protocol by using the `https://` URL that GitHub shows you for your repository.

*(Update: to my surprise, some people apparently thought that by this I was suggesting that "https" means "smart HTTP", which I wasn't. Git used to have a "dumb HTTP" protocol which didn't allow pushing before the "smart HTTP" that GitHub uses was introduced - either could be used over either `http` or `https`. The differences between the transfer protocols used by Git are explained in the link below.)*

If you want to change the URL of origin, you can just do:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

or

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

More information is available in *[10.6 Git Internals - Transfer Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols)*.

Comment: So i changed the URL and retried the push, get this error now -   ERROR: my_user_name/my_repo.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Is the URL you've set definitely the one that you can copy-and-paste from the page for your repository on GitHub?  (It's case sensitive, incidentally.)

Comment: well the repo has not been created yet on github, so when I try http://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo ...not sure if thats what you meant

Comment: OK, well you have to create the repository on GitHub before you can push to it - when you do so, it'll give you instructions on how to clone or push to the repository.

Comment: Cool. I am also a newbie to Github. My very first exploration of github was successful. When I tried doing it for a second time for a different project, I ended up in the same error saying "github error: .git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?". After reading through Mark Longair's suggestion, I created a new repo in Github. I did it through this link http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/. A direct link to create a new repository in your github account is https://github.com/repositories/new It went fine :)

Comment: I just had this very same problem.  Actually the problem was that you have slash "/" right in between github.com and your username.  And it should be a colon ":".  That is the problem :D

Comment: @WilmerEHenaoH: that might have been *your* problem, but it wasn't the problem in the question or with in my answer ;) (Just for interest, there is sometimes confusion over [the two styles of SSH URL in git](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5281822/223092), one of which uses a colon to separate hostname and path and the other of which doesn't.)

Comment: "https" means "secure HTTP", not "smart HTTP".

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - I wasn't suggesting that it was! I've added a clarification.

Comment: Hi Mark. Your sentence *"the "smart HTTP" protocol by using the https:// URL that GitHub shows you for your repository*" is not clear. With your added clarification your answer becomes correct. Please rework your answer in order to make it simple and without ambiguity => Please rephrase the unclear/ambiguous sentences and merge your clarification paragraph within the first paragraph. Cheers

Answer (score 38):

Use [Mark Longair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548661/git-github-cant-push-to-master/7548684#7548684), but make sure to use the HTTPS link to the repository:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

You can use then `git push origin master`.

Comment: It works for me. Then just type `git push` also works.

Answer (score 13):

Mark Longair's solution using `git remote set-url...` is quite clear.  You can also get the same behavior by directly editing this section of the .git/config file:

before:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

after:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

(And conversely, the `git remote set-url...` invocation produces the above change.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution to this for someone new to this:

Edit the configuration file in your local .git directory (`config`). Change `git:` to `https:` below.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/your_username/your_repo
```

Comment: Incorrect, https protocol will not allow pushes.  See:  "Pro Git" book, section 4.1.4 "HTTP/S Protocol".  Link: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: @KevinJ.Rice: uhm, where does it say *that*? Github uses the smart HTTP protocol and that allows for pushes *just fine*.

Answer (score 2):

The below cmnds will fix the issue.

```
 git pull --rebase
 git push
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue **after upgrading the Git client**, and suddenly my repository could not push.

I found that some old remote had the wrong value of `url`, even through my currently active remote had the same value for `url` and was working fine.

But there was also the `pushurl` param, so adding it for the old remote worked for me:

Before:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

*NOTE: This part of file "config" was unused for ages, but the new client complained about the wrong URL:*

```
[remote "composer"]
    url = git://github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/composer/*
```

So I added the `pushurl` param to the old remote:

```
[remote "composer"]
    url = git://github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/composer/*
    pushurl = git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you clone a repo using a call like:

```
git clone git://github.com/....git
```

This essentially sets you up as a pull-only user, who can't push up changes.

I fixed this by opening my repo's `.git/config` file and changing the line:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
```

to:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh+git://git@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
```

This `ssh+git` protocol with the `git` user is the authentication mechanism preferred by Github.

The other answers mentioned here technically work, but they all seem to bypass ssh, requiring you to manually enter a password, which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo you will see a textbox where you can select the git path to your repository. You'll want to use this!

Answer (score 0):

I added my pubkey to github.com and this was successful:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

But I received the "You can't push" error after having wrongly done this:

```
git clone git://github.com/mygithubacct/dotfiles.git
git remote add origin git@github.com:mygithubacct/dotfiles.git
...edit/add/commit
git push origin master
```

Instead of doing what I should have done:

```
mkdir dotfiles
cd dotfiles
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:mygithubacct/dotfiles.git
git pull origin master
...edit/add/commit
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

To set `https` globally instead of `git://`:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way yuo get over it is to replace `origin` with the suggestion it gives.

Instead of `git push origin master`, use:

```
git push git@github.com:my_user_name/my_repo.git master
```