# Can't push to github website

Tags: git

I am trying to use Jekyll on github but can't seem to push to update the files. I am new to git and have no problems pushing to repo's that I make but when trying to push to my site I keep getting these errors:

> You can't push to `git://github.com/anthonybrown/anthonybrown.github.com.git`
>   Use `git@github.com:anthonybrown/anthonybrown.github.com.git`

I have been trying to do this for 3 days now and have a page up.

Comment: There is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548661
Try apply first answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the URL of your git-remote to the correct one.

The command to change the URL is this (assuming the remote is named `origin`):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:anthonybrown/anthonybrown.github.com.git
```

If the remote has a different name and you do not know it, have a look at the output of `git remote`.

Of course you could also simple edit `.git/config` and replace the old `git://...` url with the correct one, but since there's a command for this there's no reason to do this.