# git github cannot push to origin

Tags: git, github, push

I may be missing something, but I'm sure that I've checked everything,
I forked a repo and cloned it on my system,
made some changes
after commiting 
did `git push origin master`

it says

```
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/my_username/my_repo.git
  Use git@github.com:my_username/my_repo.git
```

Am I missing something?
then I tried 

`git remote add origin https://github.com/my_username/my_repo.git`

it returned

fatal: remote origin already exists.

I dont understand why this is hapenning, pls help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The url with

```
git://github.com/my_username/my_repo.git
```

git:// Only gives read only access as mentioned in the side too..

[image]

Whereas,

```
git@github.com:my_username/my_repo.git
```

gives read and write access as mentioned in site

[image]

Though, `https://github.com/my_username/my_repo.git` also has read and write access but it was not working in your case because you trying to create a new remote with the same name instead of resetting it. The correct syntax as mentioned was

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:my_username/my_repo.git`

And

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/my_username/my_repo.git
```

would also work.

Answer (score 5):

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:my_username/my_repo.git`

Comment: that worked and I'll accept this answer after the time limit, bt can you eplain me what the problem was? and many thnks

Comment: I think https url is only for read only repository fetching. But git@github also gives write and read access.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this does not work is, that the git:// protocol, which you chose for cloning, is only configured for read access at Github (since it only would support anonymous write access without access restrictions).
Github supports both ssh (git@github.com...) and https for write access to repositories.

Your second command fails, because when you clone, git already creates a remote named origin. So if you want to add another remote repository, you have to give another name.